# node.js is a sever or an engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new in js and nodejs. I am studing about nodejs in different web sites like w3schools. I learned that nodejs is a kind of server that can run js in the backend of a website . but my mentor told me it is not a server . it is just an engine in the server that can run js. now I am a little confused. I hope someone tell me what exactly nodejs is or tell me a good reference to learn about nodejs.
thank you

Comment: What do you understand as "a server"?

Comment: @VLAZ  server is the place that response to our request... I mean when we send a request from a client it goes to the web host. that host is our server and send the response to our client... this is the definition of a server in my mind

Comment: If by "server" you mean "web server" than no, node is not a web server. But you can build one on top of it.

Comment: _I learned that nodejs is a kind of server_ - nodejs is a runtime that allows you to write and execute javascript outside of the browser environment. You can create a server using `http` module of nodejs or a nodejs framework like `express`.

Comment: Also you could always start from [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/about/)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I even don't know the difference between web server and server . I think they have the same definition except a web server is for web application. I think I need more studies about servers ... thank you anyway

Comment: @Yousaf with this definition ,it is not a server . I think I understand what you said ... thank you very much

Comment: Both [engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_engine) and [server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing)) are terms that are used for so many different things that you can basically call everything a server or an engine without being technically wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mentor is wrong, but still kind of right.

> Node.js is an open source server environment.

Originally, it came into existence when the developers of JavaScript extended it from something you could only run in the browser to something you could run on your machine as a standalone application.

Nowadays, it's a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome’s V8 JavaScript engine.

Now, this is as you can see indeed a server as it serves your javascript files. However, in difference to a php server, Node.js is designed without threads.

But that doesn't mean you can't take advantage of multiple cores in your environment, and is something I believe your mentor aren't aware of.

---

**Conclusion**

> Node. js is an **application** runtime environment that **allows you to write server-side applications** in JavaScript. Thanks to its unique **I/O model**, it excels at the sort of scalable and real-time situations we are increasingly demanding of our servers.

Comment: It is not a server and doesn't 'serve your JavaScript files' - it is a JavaScript runtime environment - it executes JavaScript. The fact that people write server side applications for it doesn't make the JRE itself a server.

Comment: Who are "the developers of JavaScript"? What's the difference between "runtime" and an "engine"? What is a "server"? Also in what way does a NodeJS server serve JS files?

Answer (score 1):

It`s an engine that give you possibility to run js scripts in standalone mode. Instead of browser mode.

Comment: Also, when you run js in browser, you have it as sandbox for your script while it opens. Because modern browser gives js functionality.  NodeJS gives you a full advantages to run your applications in standalone , background, GUI and so on. According nodejs posibilites it`s also possible build servers with it. You can build your server by your self or take solutions and toolkits, that gives needed functionality.

Comment: you mean it is not a server, then my mentor is right

Comment: Yes. I mean it is engine firstly. And it`s advanced feature that you can run interpreted scripts with near  of  compiled apps perfomance.  Please also note, that JS syntax rules may some differ with browser, and some versions of node js.

Comment: You can [edit] your answer, at the moment the comments here are more accurate than the one sentence in your answer ...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Sergey that node js is engine firstly.
Node.js allows the creation of Web servers and networking tools using JavaScript and a collection of "modules" that handle various core functionalities.Modules are provided for file system I/O, networking (DNS, HTTP, TCP, TLS/SSL, or UDP), binary data (buffers), cryptography functions, data streams, and other core functions. Node.js's modules use an API designed to reduce the complexity of writing server applications.

you can learn about node.js from [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_intro.asp)
and [Tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_introduction.htm) are best sites for node.js learning

Comment: What are "best sites"? Please reduce opinion to the minimum.

Comment: i have mentioned both sites from where i have learned both are the best sites are the best sites for the beginner